# Creating a custom BIRT emitter: How to get the width and height of a cell, table or grid?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, reporting, birt

i am implementing **a custom Birt emitter** and i need to know the **width and height** of a cell, table or grid in pixels or points. The issue ocurrs if the measures are not explicitly set in the Report Designer.

I tried to get these infos by calling **cellContent.getWidth()** and **cellContent.getComputedStyle().getWidth()**. The first one returns null, the second one throws a "createUnsupportedPropertyException" exception.

I am using **Birt 2.6.**

Can anyone give me a hint how to get this done?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you would like to hear, but...

I once tried to understand how the page-oriented emitters actually work at all (see below).

The source code doesn't help much in this regard, it's just too complicated to understand it
- in particular, in comparison to other libraries like e.g. [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.org).

And I wasn't able to find any documentation in the Internet describing the layout algorithm.

My guess is that - apart from a few developers working for Actuate - nobody is able to implement a custom page-oriented emitter.

---

What I was trying to achieve then was: render a grid at the *bottom* of the last page.
Sounds easy? Well, I gave up.

Something I *was* able to do: Avoid some unnecessary nested tables in the WordEmitter output.